facebook login with react-native-fbsdk-next and OAuth
THe app I'm working with uses expo-auth-session/providers/facebook for facebook authentication. I have to change the implementation because this is now deprecated and the way to go is with react-native-fbsdk-next. Correct me if I'm wrong but the docs for that are not super useful.
Would you be able to tell me if the react-native-fbsdk-next library can be used without OAuth?
I am completely new to the flow of authentication with Facebook so trying to find the most efficient way to fix this. Also point me if you have - any resources about this
Thanks!!
I know that I have to add iOS and Android platforms on the Meta dev - I tried to do that but the API is currently restricted so I'm going in circles.
